# Put words inside span tag using emmet

Tags: html, tags, emmet

I want to do add a description to a tag (eg. span) using the Emmet shortcuts to get something like this:

```
<span> Description </span>
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to [use braces for text content](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#text-), e.g.

```
span{ Description }
```